# "no default member for type integer" error when accessing multiple gridkeys

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with 2 data keys.
Gridview is defined like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1"    runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID1, ID2" >
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="ID1" Visible="false"> </asp:BoundField>    
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="ID2" Visible="false"> </asp:BoundField>                     
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Full Name" DataField="fullname" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
<HeaderStyle Width="350px" /> </asp:BoundField>
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="button" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn" ControlStyle-Width="30px" CommandName="Select" 
 HeaderText="" Text="+" ItemStyle-Width="30px" />
</Columns>
```

Then in the VB code behind I have a sub to handle the gridview command:

```
Protected Sub grid1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object,ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grid1.RowCommand
    Dim currentCommand As String = e.CommandName
    If currentCommand = "Select" Then
        Dim currentRowIndex As Integer = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        Dim id1 As Integer = grid1.DataKeys(currentRowIndex).Value("ID1")
        Dim id2 As Integer = grid1.DataKeys(currentRowIndex).Value("ID2")
        '***call another sub with these IDs***
    End If
End Sub
```

When I try running this I get a "No default member found for type integer" error with the code breaking at the Dim id1.... line.

I have also tried referring to the multiple datakeys as (0) and (1) but get the same issue.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schoolboy Error!
Should have been...

```
    Dim id1 As Integer = grid1.DataKeys(currentRowIndex).Values("ID1")
    Dim id2 As Integer = grid1.DataKeys(currentRowIndex).Values("ID2")
```

i.e. Value**s** instead of Value!